# Остановка и рестарт кнопки с таймером Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть кнопка с таймером, которая соответственно запускает таймер. Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии второй раз на кнопку таймер останавливался и сбрасывался, а если нажать 3 раз, то снова запускался и так далее?

```
mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment1);
mTimer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFragment1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new CountDownTimer(80000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimer.setText("It left:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimer.setText("Care!!!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить флаг состояния таймера `boolean isTimerStarted = false`, к примеру. При нажатии на кнопку проверять флаг и если таймер не запущен - запускать, иначе - останавливать:

```
if(!isTimerStarted) {
    countDownTimer.start();
    isTimerStarted = true;
} else {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    isTimerStarted = false;
}
```

Comment: Я новичек в этом деле. Можете подсказать? Если я правильно понял, то код if else надо вставить в `public void onClick(View v) {}`  над кодом с таймером?
@VAndrJ

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, вместо кода с таймером. А объявление таймера вынести к объявлению остальных элементов.

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, но как вынести таймер к объявлению остальных элементов? @VAndrJ

Comment: @ЛевНауменко перед `mButton.setOnClickListener` объявите `final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(все остальное`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, но есть одно "но", при открытии фрагмента таймер запускается сразу же без нажатия кнопки. @VAndrJ

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, при объявлении не указываете `.start()`? Если да, то уберите, управление должно быть в `listener`